# Require a COUNTIF Formulation that is not available on search option

Tags: countif

Could you please help I need a COUNTIF formula. 
The range is Cell A1 to Cell N1, the criteria is if there is a text with A the value of A should be 1 in the answer, and if the text is H the value should be 0.5?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:N1,"A")+COUNTIF(A1:N1,"H")*0.5
```

though you might be better off entering `1` instead of `A` and `.5` instead of `H` and just using `=SUM`.

This is not case sensitive (`A` or `a` should work equally).